# where is scikit dataset stored on computer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I ran the following code

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
```

and it took a couple of minutes the first time with the message:

```
Downloading 20news dataset. This may take a few minutes.
Downloading dataset from https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5975967 (14 MB)
```

The next time it was instantaneous , so python has obviously pulled the dataset to my laptop. 
Is this like a csv file?
Where is it stored? 
And how do I save it into a specific folder so that i dont have to download it again when say I restart my machine

Comment: In my windows, it was stored in `C:\Users\<user-name>\scikit_learn_data`. 

I downloaded MNIST data set with `fetch_openml()` function with default download location. The data file was located in `C:\Users\<user-name>\scikit_learn_data\openml\openml.org\data\v1\download` as a zip file.

Answer (score 2):

If not specified, downloaded data by [fetch_20newsgroups](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups.html) is stored in '~/scikit_learn_data' subfolders by default.

> data_home : optional, default: None
>
> Specify a download and cache folder for the datasets. If None,
>   all scikit-learn data is stored in '~/scikit_learn_data' subfolders.

You can change it by setting up **data_home** parameter:

```
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(data_home=<Another Directory>)
```

Comment: yes, I tracked it down to the scikit_learn_data folder. It is stored as a .pkz file. And adding this line after the import like did store it in a different folder. But how do I ensure that when i run the import next time it will pick up from this stored location and not go to the net to download?

Comment: This is a cache folder also, so sklearn wan’t download it again if already downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

For existing datasets:
according [the github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/datasets/base.py#L686) data seems to be saved next to the scikit module path:

```
def load_boston(return_X_y=False):
# ...
    module_path = dirname(__file__)

    fdescr_name = join(module_path, 'descr', 'boston_house_prices.rst')
    with open(fdescr_name) as f:
        descr_text = f.read()

    data_file_name = join(module_path, 'data', 'boston_house_prices.csv')
```

so look for: `<module>\data\filename`

For data fetched:

see [this scikit doc page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups), quoting:

```
sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(
    data_home=None, # this is what you're looking for
    subset=’train’,
    categories=None,
    shuffle=True,
    random_state=42,
    remove=(),
    download_if_missing=True)
```

> data_home : optional, default: None
>
> Specify a download and cache folder for the datasets. If None, all scikit-learn data is stored in `~/scikit_learn_data` subfolders.

Comment: thanks,. It is stored as a .pkz file. And adding this line after the import
```
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(data_home=<Another Directory>)
```
 like did store it in a different folder. But how do I ensure that when i run the import next time it will pick up from this stored location and not go to the net to download?